# JS Memory Leak while trying to split text node

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a text node in a p tag say "Hello". I wrote two function which search for a specific string and split the text node into multiple text nodes each containing only the specific string. I'm getting the output of the function printed to console in both chrome and firefox but right after that the ram usage goes over up to 1.5GB in chrome and it crashes and in case of firefox it uses 100% of ram forcing me to do a reboot. Why is this happening ?
Here are the two functions that I'm using :

```
   var splitIntoNodes = function(s,v){
      var i=0,j=0,nodeText,pos,t; var fNodes = [];
      for(i;i<s.length;i++){
         if(s[i].nodeName=="#text"){
            t = makeNodes(s[i],v);
            for(j=0;i<t.length;j++) fNodes.push(t[j]);
         } else {
            t = splitIntoNodes(s[i].childNodes,v);
            for(j=0;i<t.length;j++) fNodes.push(t[j]);
         }
      }
      return fNodes;
   }

   var makeNodes = function(s,v){
      var p = s.nodeValue.search(v),q,r,fNodes = [];
      while(p>=0){
         q = s.splitText(0,p);
         r = s.splitText(0,v.length);
         fNodes.push(r);
         p = r.nodeValue.search(v);
      }
      console.log(fNodes);
      return fNodes;
   }

// usage : splitIntoNodes(document.querySelector("id").childNodes),"a_string");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(j=0;i<t.length;j++) fNodes.push(t[j]);`

Is an infinite loop if `i` is less than `t.length`.

Do you mean to use `j` for the loop condition? i.e. : `j < t.length`?

If so, the same error is repeated a couple of lines down.

Comment: well, actually yea. I did meant to use j inplace of i. I'll investigate and post an update

Comment: We'll that's kinda silly mistake . Thanks mate. It fixed it